# Google Oauth2 redirects after 2.1 minutes on login

Tags: django, nginx, google-oauth, uwsgi

The problem with my Django App is that the Google Oath2 Redirect takes 2 minutes to login. I am using uwsgi + nginx on the server-side. It only happens on the login request.I had earlier tried using Nginx + Gunicorn,

nginx error logs said something about Connection reset by peer(104).But i don't think the error is with nginx. It still doesn't work even if I disable nginx.

The stack trace when running the server on django dev server:

[image]

The Google Oauth2 Takes 2.1 minutes of time.

[image]

Any Suggestions? Pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on a server 2 weeks ago. In my case, the server was resolving all URLs using ipv6. It would take 2 minutes to resolve each URL. So, I just turned off ipv6.

Try disabling it.